# Firebase, multi location updates

Tags: firebase, atomic, firebase-security

Consider the following code for atomic writes across multiple locations in FireBase:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");

var newPostRef = ref.child("posts").push();
var newPostKey = newPostRef.key();

var updatedUserData = {};
updatedUserData["users/"+authData.uid+"/posts/" + newPostKey] = true;
updatedUserData["posts/" + newPostKey] = {
  title: "New Post",
  content: "Here is my new post!"
};

ref.update(updatedUserData, function(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Error updating data:", error);
  }
});
```

This approach could be used to update the post at different locations, but how to enforce the atomic update at the server side? (via rules).

How can I make sure that the users cannot update the location `/posts/` (via its direct reference) without populating the `users/UID/posts/` or vice versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possible such "business rules", so I'll pick one and implement that. Let's say that any post that a user refers to must exist. So you can only write to `/users/myuid/posts/mypostid` if `/posts/mypostid` exists. I'll also implement basic validation of the posts themselves.

```
{
  "posts": {
    "$postid": {
      ".validate": "hasChildren(['title', 'content'])",
      "title": {
        ".validate": "newData.isString()"
      },
      "content": {
        ".validate": "newData.isString()"
      },
      "$other": {
        ".validate": false
      }
    }
  },
  "users": {
    "$uid": {
      "posts": {
        "$postid": {
          ".validate": "newData.parent().parent().parent().parent().child('posts').child($postid).exists()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The biggest trick here is the `newData.parent().parent()...` bit, which ensures that we get the posts in the new data.

You have a habit of asking things like "how can I ensure that method ABC was used to update the data?", which is rarely the right way to think about matters. In the rules above I focus on validating the structure of the data and really don't care what API calls might lead to that data.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I was using a similar approach, but I was confusing myself with the use of newData.val() instead of the `exists()`.. by the way, I just added "source of update" part to make it clear for readers that I'm looking for a server side solution that guarantees the right output, no matter what has happened at the client side... but anyway thanks for the answer. Solved my problem :)

Comment: If you already have an approach that doesn't work, **always** post what you have in your question. It shows that you've already tried something, plus it allows us to copy/paste snippets into our answer.

Comment: refering to this question, can `newData.parent()...` can be used multiple times inside a `".validate"`  rule of a specific node?